# Even-indexed and odd-indexed - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code for a program which:

**1.** Asks the number of words which you want to enter.

**2.** Takes the words as the input and for each word, displays the characters at even positions and the characters at odd positions.[0 is considered as an even position]

So I wrote this code but it shows an error which says "Array cannot be resolved to a variable". I am not able to figure out where I have gone wrong.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Trying4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of words: ");

        int T = in.nextInt();

        for(int m = 0; m<T; m++) {
            String S = in.nextLine();
            int N = S.length();
            char array[] = new char[N];
            for(int n = 0; n<N; n++) {
                array[n] = S.charAt(n+1);
            }
            display(N);
        }
    }

    public static void display(int N) {
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i = i + 2) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }

        System.out.print(" ");

        for(int j = 1; j<N; j = j + 2) {
            System.out.print(array[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: classic school work, what's the error?

Comment: It shows the error "Array cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: You need to pass the array to the `display()` function.

Comment: Like it's not Java at all.

Comment: Other than the common convention of using `i` as a loop counter, there is no reason for your variable names to be a single character. Further, using a single capital letter (like `T`) is confusing to the reader because of [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Comment: Not only. Java must be readable. Have you ever seen in Spring what kind of names they choose? Like e.g. `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. This way you don't need comments and explanation. You just read the code. What is `N` ? What is `T` ? Newton? Tesla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There error is being produced because `array` is being using in `display` which is outside of the scope you declared it in.

To fix that, you can either declare `array` as an instance variable (outside of any methods), or pass the array as a parameter to `display`.

Also, to get a character array from the string, use `S.toCharArray()`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Trying4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of words: ");
        int numWords = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine(); // consume the new-line character after the number
        for(int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
            char[] word = in.nextLine().toCharArray();
            display(word);
        }
    }
    public static void display(char[] word) {
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i += 2) {
            System.out.print(word[i]);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int i = 1; i < word.length; j += 2) {
            System.out.print(word[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to help with eliminating the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I added the repaired code. It also needed to consume the newline character after the number in the `Scanner`.

Comment: My bad. I didn't rename all the variables consistently. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with your code, starting from violating **naming conventions** and **code identation** rules to **compile time errors** (array variable used out of the scope/block it was declared) to **runtime errors** (wrong index passed at chatAt()). Even if that code was running ok, any experienced developer would reject it instantly.

I've pasted below a **cleaner working version** (still I wouldn't implement it in this way (no need for that array, a String object would be enough), but it is the closest to what you've had originally) :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Trying4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of words: ");
        int nrWords = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        for (int counter = 0; counter < nrWords; counter++) {
            System.out.print("Word[" + counter + "] : ");
            String word = scanner.nextLine();
            int length = word.length();
            char array[] = new char[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                array[i] = word.charAt(i);
            }
            display(length, array);
        }
    }

    public static void display(int N, char[] array) {
        System.out.print("Result EVEN : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + 2) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }

        System.out.print("\nResult ODD : ");

        for (int j = 1; j < N; j = j + 2) {
            System.out.print(array[j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails with compile-time error.

You need to change your method `public static void display(int N)` to `public static void display(char[] array, int N)` and pass it the array inside your `main` method: `display(array, N);`

It it your only problem or do you have any other issues?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the array to the `display()` function.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Trying4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of words: ");

    int T = in.nextInt();

    for(int m = 0; m<T; m++)
        {
        String S = in.nextLine();
        int N = S.length();
        char array[] = new char[N];
        for(int n = 0; n<N; n++)
            {
            array[n] = S.charAt(n);
        }
        display(N, array);
        }
    }

public static void display(int N, char[] array){

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i = i + 2)
        {
          System.out.print(array[i]);
        }

    System.out.print(" ");

    for(int j = 1; j<N; j = j + 2)
        {
        System.out.print(array[j]);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I changed the above code. Using `S.charAt(n+1)` was causing it to overrun the array. This is different from your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little tip to tidy up the code too, there's a built in method called toCharArray() whose name is self explanatory and eliminates that loop you're using. `char array[] = in.NextLine().toCharArray();`

Answer (score 0):

If I may touch your code, because people mostly get frustrated when touching the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int wordCount = getInt(sc, "Enter the number of words: ");
    int wordIndex = 1; // Just to type a message "Word 1, word 2, etc."
    sc.nextLine();
    while (wordCount > 0) {
        System.out.printf("Type word %s: ", wordIndex);
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        List<Character> oddPosChars = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> evenPosChars = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                evenPosChars.add(word.charAt(i));
            } else {
                oddPosChars.add(word.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        print(evenPosChars, "Even Characters: ");
        print(oddPosChars, "Odd Characters: ");
        wordCount--;
        wordIndex++;
    }
}

static int getInt(Scanner sc, String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
    sc.next();
    System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again.");
    return getInt(sc, message);
}

static void print(List<Character> characters, String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    characters.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Or if you're sure you want to use arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int wordCount = getInt(sc, "Enter the number of words: ");
    int wordIndex = 1; // Just to type a message "Word 1, word 2, etc."
    sc.nextLine();
    while (wordCount > 0) {
        System.out.printf("Type word %s: ", wordIndex);
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        char[] evenPosChars = new char[word.length() - (word.length() / 2)];
        char[] oddPosChars = new char[word.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                evenPosChars[i / 2] = word.charAt(i);
            } else {
                oddPosChars[(i - 1) / 2] = word.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        print(evenPosChars, "Even Characters: ");
        print(oddPosChars, "Odd Characters: ");
        wordCount--;
        wordIndex++;
    }
}

static int getInt(Scanner sc, String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
    sc.next();
    System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again.");
    return getInt(sc, message);
}

static void print(char[] characters, String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    for (char character : characters) {
        System.out.print(character);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
 private static void ex(String S) {
  char c[] = S.toCharArray();
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
   System.out.print(c[i]);
   i += 1;
  }
  for (j = 1; j < c.length; j++) {
   System.out.print(c[j]);
   j += 1;
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int T = scan.nextInt();
  while (hasNext()) {
   for (int m = 0; m <= = T; m++) {
    String S = scan.next();
    ex(S);
    System.out.println();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It might be interesting for the user that asked the question if you added a short description of the code snippet you posted.